# Does AirCanada provide long layover (24+ hr) accommodation?

Tags: accommodation, layovers, air-canada

Once I flew from Milano Malpensa, Italy, to Entebbe, Uganda, with Turkish Airlines. After booking the flight (yes, I was young and stupid) I realized I had a 24+ layover in Istanbul so I called Turkish Airlines and I asked if they had some kind of accommodation and, to my big surprise, they booked a 4* hotel for me all for free.

I haven't had any other long layover since so I'm not sure whether this is common or not.

My question is: I'm flying AirCanada to Cuba with a long layover to Toronto, am I eligible for some kind of airline-paid accommodation?

Comment: What year was that? What class fare were you flying?

Comment: Yes, I'd be interested to know more details about the itinerary too - its unlikely for economy passengers to get a deal like that from any airlines these days!

Comment: It was August 2011 and it definitely was economy class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that the room you got is specifically a service of Turkish to encourage you to connect through Istanbul. There is a general question on this at [Does a layover of more than 6 hours entitle me to accommodation by the airline?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17723/does-a-layover-of-more-than-6-hrs-entitle-me-to-accomodation-by-the-airlines). The answers there agree that in general, airlines don't give you free hotel rooms just because you have a layover.

That said, [Air Canada does have a program](http://www.aircanada.com/en/travelinfo/traveller/stopover/index.html) that will give you a free room:

> For connections over 6 hours, the Air Canada Stopover option includes one-night hotel accommodation and applicable taxes for one low price. The Canadian break comes at no additional airfare and your hotel is free with a Business Class, Premium Economy or Latitude and for a minimal fee with a Flex or Tango fare.

So in this particular case you are (once again) lucky.